# How to modify bindings to match ECB window numbers?

Tags: window, key-bindings

ECB windows display their number: `W-0`, `W-1`, etc.

Is there a way to define bindings so that I can get to these windows using bindings such as `C-c . w 0`, `C-c . w 1`, rather than using `C-c . g d` to go to directories, `C-c . g s` to go to sources?

[image]

Alternatively, is there a way to display the key bindings for the windows in the frame modelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what to do, and how to discover it :)

Navigating to one of these windows, we see that the local value of `mode-line-format` is:

```
((:eval
  (car
   (ecb-mode-line-make-modeline-str
    (format " W-%d"
            (1-
             (ecb-window-in-window-list-number
              (ecb-canonical-windows-list))))
   ecb-mode-line-win-nr-face)))
 (#(" " 0 1
    (face ecb-mode-line-prefix-face)))
 (#("/Volumes/Home/hodiquey/Projects/git/ecb" 0 39
    (help-echo "Mouse-2 toggles maximizing, mouse-3 displays a popup-menu" face ecb-mode-line-data-face))))
```

Therefore, `ecb-window-in-window-list-number` and `ecb-canonical-windows-list` are the key (and the actual numbers is 1 more than what's displayed)

You can then do something like

```
(defun my-jump-to-ecb-number (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((winlist (ecb-canonical-windows-list)))
    (select-window
     (cdr
      (assoc (+ n 1)
             (mapcar (lambda (win)
                       (cons (ecb-window-in-window-list-number winlist win)
                             win))
                     winlist))))))
```

And use it with something like

```
(define-key ecb-mode-map (kbd "w 0") (lambda () (interactive) (my-jump-to-ecb-number 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution would be:

1. Use `describe-key` (<kbd>C-h k</kbd>) or `describe-key-briefly`(<kbd>C-h c</kbd>) to get the names of the commands invoked by the original bindings:

   - <kbd>C-h c</kbd> <kbd>C-c . g d</kbd>
   - <kbd>C-h c</kbd> <kbd>C-c . g s</kbd>
2. Set up additional bindings for the commands:

   ```
   (define-key ecb-mode-map (kbd "w 0") 'goto-dirs)
   (define-key ecb-mode-map (kbd "w 1") 'goto-sources)
   ```

   ... where `goto-dirs` and `goto-sources` are the names of the commands you obtained in step 1.

Comment: that wouldn't work too well when switching layouts (which would potentially change the number associated with dirs/sources)